# How can i convert a big gltf file to jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, gltf

i have a 3d scene in blender and wanted to use it in my react three fiber project but after exporting to gltf i found a 300k line in the file. the file works fine in normal threejs but when i execute the command
npx gltfjsx public/models/map.gltf
It stays stuck for a while.
Is my gltf file too big for gltfjsx ?

the jsx file is created but still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender, try exporting it as "glTF Binary" (producing a `*.glb` file), or use "glTF Separate" (which will produce a collection of files that must be shared as a group).

Don't use the "glTF Embedded" option in Blender.  It will produce a JSON-formatted `*.gltf` file that contains base64-encoded textures and mesh data, resulting in lines over 300k long as you discovered.  This is an archaic option that is under consideration for removal from Blender.

Answer (score 0):

use [gltfjsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltfjsx) npm module:

```
npx gltfjsx model.gltf --transform
```

This will create a Model.jsx file that plots out all of the assets contents.